# ANSI vs UTF-8 in web Browser

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, character-encoding, ansi

My requirement is to allow users to use(type) ANSI characters instead of utf-8 when they are typing in to the text fields of my webpages.

I looked at the setting of the character set in html meta tag

```
 <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

That was helpful to display the content in ANSI instead of UTF-8, but it does not stop users typing in utf-8. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Users will always type what they want, and send to your server what they want. It is only of interest how your server handles that correctly.

Comment: Hi Bergi, How can I know what encoding is used by the user. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the form attributes enctype="multipart/form-data" and accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's distinguish between two things here: *characters the user can type* and the *encoding used to send this data* to the server. These are two separate issues.

A user can type anything they want into a form in their browser. For all intents and purposes these characters have no encoding at this point, they're pure "text"; encodings do not play a role just yet and you cannot restrict the set of available characters with encodings.

Once the user submits the form, the browser will have to encode this data into binary somehow, which is where an encoding comes in. Ultimately the browser decides how to encode the data, but it will choose the encoding specified in the HTTP headers, meta elements and/or `accept-charset` attribute of the form. The latter should always by the deciding factor, but you'll find buggy behaviour in the real world (*cough*cough*IE*cough*). In practice, all three character set definitions should be identical to not cause any confusion there.

Now, if your user typed in some "exotic" characters and the browser has decided to encode the data in "ANSI" and the chosen encoding cannot represent those exotic characters, then the browser will typically replace those characters with HTML entities. So, even in this case it doesn't *restrict* the allowed characters, it simply finds a different way to encode them.

> How can I know what encoding is used by the user

You cannot. You can only specify which character set you would *like* to receive and then double check that that's actually what you *did* receive. If the expectation doesn't match, reject the input (an HTTP `400 Bad Request` response may be in order).

If you want to limit the acceptable set of characters a user may input, you need to do this by checking and rejecting *characters* independent of their encoding. You can do this in Javascript at input time, and will ultimately need to do this on the server again (since browser-side Javascript ultimately has no influence on what can get submitted to the server).

Comment: Surely you are using "pure text" as a rhetorical device. The problem with that is encouraging a programmer to believe there is such a thing. HTML4+ browsers and their JavaScript implementations use the Unicode character set and its UTF-16 encoding for JavaScript string operations.The programmer will need to know this when using JavaScript to limit character at input time, as you suggest.

Comment: Yes and no. While there are implementation specific considerations, the JavaScript API essentially tries to expose text at the level of characters instead of byte arrays. But yes, I mostly wanted to make that distinction clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the encoding of the page to UTF-8 in a  and/or HTTP header, it will be interpreted as UTF-8, unless the user deliberately goes to the View->Encoding menu and selects a different encoding, overriding the one you specified.

In that case, accept-encoding would have the effect of setting the submission encoding back to UTF-8 in the face of the user messing about with the page encoding. However, this still won't work in IE, due the previous problems discussed with accept-encoding in that browser.

So it's IMO doubtful whether it's worth including accept-charset to fix the case where a non-IE user has deliberately sabotaged the page encoding